# which SQL Server version I have to install to work with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have to learn ASP.net. For this which SQL Server I have to install on my pc. I have already installed Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Any version you like. You may as well go for the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter actually. You can access any SQL Server (2000 up to 2014) from .NET. So I'd go for the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you install VS a SQL Server Express should be already installed on your system (in case of VS 2010 it should be SQL Server 2008). For new developments where you dont' have a specific version as a requirement it is beter to install a newer version, such as SQL Server 2012 or 2014.